# creating dynamic hyperlinks when importing data into excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to automate a process where data is queried from the database, downloaded into an excel file and sent to recipients. One of the column in the excel file needs to be a hyperlink. How can i make this happen?

1. I selected =hyperlink(A,B) into the column but the function appears as text and not as hyperlink.
2. I tried changing the web options to 'update links on save' but it does not help.
3. Only when i click in the cell and hit enter does the hyperlink appear. This is not an option
4. Opening the file and adding a new column to use the hyperlink function is not an option either since the process is being automated.
5. The tool allows me to export into an xlsx and not a xlsm so i am assuming i cannot use macros to do the job.

I tried researching the answers for similar questions but didnt find any that i could use which will generate a url dynamically without me having to open the file. Any ideas?

I also tried another tool and they were able to send out emails with links. I do not know how they do it internally but i do not see any hyperlink functions when i tab into the hyperlink column.

Answer (score 0):

Cell type should probably be set to "Generic".

You may also need to trigger a "Refresh" after the workbook is filled with all the data. Sometimes I need to that manually - but only once. I have no idea why it happens.

Comment: 2022 calling. This is still an issue in the latest version of Excel (Version 2210 Build 16.0.15726.20070). Cell format is already General and Refresh All does nothing. Only clicking on the cell and pressing enter on the formula bar evaluates the formula.

Comment: *"I selected =hyperlink(A,B) into the column"* - how did you do that? Manually? With a script? Which language? Run from where? You might be able to use VBS if you create an additional .xlsm, which will process the .xlsm in order to trigger the update. Or find another way to talk to excel to do the same thing.

Comment: Not sure how the OP did it, but I had it in a CSV file as text and tried to import it in Excel via the data import from text tool

Comment: In some situation when the screen did not update during a calculation, I used the following commands:         ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True;
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True;
        Application.Calculation = xlManual;
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic; I played with them placing them in different combination, different order, and different places (even more than once) until they did the job. I cannot guarantee which one did the trick, but somehow in the end they helped.